# How can we delete Azure DevOps environment (Pipeline->environment) automatically

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

I am having multiple Azure DevOps pipeline environment. Time to time i want to cleanup few unused environments, which i am doing manually now a days.

I see one API but not sure it works.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/environments/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0

Any script or pipeline setup will be appreciated to automated this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Environments - Delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/environments/delete?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0) api:

```
DELETE https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/distributedtask/environments/{environmentId}?api-version=7.0
```

Just give the `environmentId` and it will be deleted.